# Mention of being more profitable if you do a business rather than a job?

Tags: bible

I am trying to find similarities between different religions on the assumption that doing business has greater good than doing a job. Is there any mention of such thing in Bible?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! We don't do verse search questions here, and also, it's not clear how you distinguish doing business from doing a job.

Comment: Hi thanks. Sorry in Islam.stackexchange we do based on verses. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think there is any Christian teaching that says it is better to do business than a job.

Answer (score 1):

In Genesis 2:15: the first instruction God gave Adam was to work: “The Lord God took the man and put him in the Garden of Eden to work it and keep it.”  That could be seen as gardening, or being a farmer.  Work is simply engaging in physical or mental activity in order to achieve a purpose or result.  In that sense, engaging in any business activity is work.

In Western culture, the word work is most commonly associated with one’s profession or means of livelihood, regardless of what that entails.  People who work are usually employed and are paid to perform certain tasks for their employer.  “Engaging in business” sounds more like being self-employed as a merchant or a banker or a shop-keeper.  However, the Bible does not advocate the pursuit of business for profit or imply that being employed is in some way inferior.

It is noteworthy that before Jesus commenced his ministry, he was a carpenter and worked alongside Joseph (Mark 6:3).

Here are a few Bible verses that talk about work (regardless of whether a person is an employee or an employer).  The priority is not about being profitable or making a name for oneself or becoming rich and influential.  Rather, the priority is to be honest, and to provide for one’s dependants:

> “The soul of the sluggard craves and gets nothing, while the soul of the diligent is richly supplied” (Proverbs 13:4).
>
> “Let the thief no longer steal, but rather let him labour, doing honest work with his own hands, so that he may have something to share with anyone in need” (Ephesians 4:28).
>
> “But if anyone does not provide for his relatives, and especially for members of his household, he has denied the faith and is worse than an unbeliever” (1 Timothy 5:8).
>
> “If anyone is not willing to work, let him not eat” (2 Thessalonians 3:10).

This verse sums it up quite simply:

> “Whatever you do, do your work heartily, as for the Lord rather than for men” (Colossians 3:23).